# How to make netcat output verbose information on macOS Mojave?

Tags: network, homebrew, macports

I've tried to use various netcat's from Brew, MacPorts, and Apple etc., but neither of them output verbose information, like "Listening to all interfaces":

```
nc -lvp 443
[No verbose output here...]
```

How can I make netcat display the verbose information I'm used to, when running netcat on e.g. Ubuntu Linux?